# Javascript Regex to match only zero/even number of backslashes anywhere in a string

Tags: javascript, angular, regex, typescript, frontend

I need a regular expression that matches the complete string with a zero/even number of backslashes anywhere in the string. If the string contains an odd number of backslashes, it should not match the complete string.

Example:

> \\ -> match

> \\\ -> does not match

> test\\test -> match

> test\\\test-> does not match

> test\\test\ -> does not match

> test\\test\\ -> match

and so on...
Note: We can assume any string of any length in place of 'test' in the above example

I am using this `^[^\\]*(\\\\)*[^\\]*$` regular expression, but it does not match the backslashes after the second test.
For example:

> test\\test(doesn't match anything after this)

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: does this work `^[^\\]*((\\\\)+[^\\]*)+$`? (non-slashes, then a group of even number of slashes followed by non-slashes, possibly repeated)

Comment: does ```a\a\\a\``` match?

Comment: `matches the complete string with a zero/even number of backslashes anywhere in the string` infers that backslashes can be anywhere in input.

Comment: Moritz Ringler, ^[^\\]*((\\\\)+[^\\]*)+$ this regex does not match any non \ characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```bash
^(?:(?:[^\\]*\\){2})*[^\\]*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FYl2ab/2)

**RegEx Breakdown:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group #1

  - `(?:`: Start non-capture group #2

    - `[^\\]*`: Match 0 or more og any char except a `\`
    - `\\`: Match a `\`
  - `){2}`: End non-capture group #2. Repeat this group 2 times.
- `)*`: End non-capture group #1. Repeat this group 0 or more times.
- `[^\\]*`: Match 0 or more og any char except a `\`
- `$`: End

Comment: *Note-to-self:* Matches also \\test\\test\\ (but I guess it's expected)

Comment: \\test\\test\ has 4 backslashes to it should match as per OP

Comment: I think you modified the regex but didn't include the updated one in the text. Should be ^(?:(?:[^\\\n]*\\){2})*[^\\\n]*$

Comment: I included `\n` in negated character class in demo because there are multiple lines of input. If we are matching a single line then `^(?:(?:[^\\]*\\){2})*[^\\]*$` would suffice.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Anubhava. The above regex works and the explanation is very clear.

Answer (score 1):

The current regular expression `^[^\\]*(\\\\)*[^\\]*$` can be interpreted as `Any(\\)*Any`, Where `Any` means any character except backslash.

The expected language shall be `Any\\Any\\Any\\...`, which can be obtained by containing the current regular expression in Kleene closure operator. That is `(Any(\\)*Any)*`

The original regular expression after modification:

`^([^\\]*(\\\\)*[^\\]*)*$`

It can be further optimized as:

`^((\\\\)*[^\\]*)*$`

Comment: @anubhava it does, doesn't it?

Comment: Sorry I meant it won't match `\a\a`

Comment: Demn, I thought he wanted the backslashes to be together

Comment: Thank you for your help, Mislah. The above regex is similar to my approach and it works, but it fails after 50 \ characters.